# Why isn't my LiveData<Drawable> being displayed as background?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-livedata

I want to change the background of a button dynamically via a LiveData object.

My ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel(Context context) {
    }

    public LiveData<Drawable> getBackDrawable(){
        MutableLiveData background = new MutableLiveData<>();
        background.postValue(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

        return background;

    }
}
```

My Xml:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="ViewModel"
            type="com.example.ckleineidam.testproject.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activation_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Button"
            android:background="@{ViewModel.getBackDrawable}" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >
</layout>
```

Why won't the drawable that I inserted into the LiveData via `.postValue()` displayed as background?

Comment: Have you tried registering an observer in the activity and setting the background manually? I am not familiar with the latest changes in the data binding library, but I don't think you can actually set a `LiveData` as a button background.

Comment: did you `setLifecycleOwner` ?

Comment: you have to add observer in your activity to set the drawable through LiveData

Comment: @AbhishekSharma : I have bound Strings and booleans previously directly. Are you saying that what's possible with Strings and booleans isn't with Drawables?

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning `LiveData<Drawable>` to `backgorund`  `property`  so you cannot achieve what you want.

`Observe` `Livedata` in your `Activity` and apply `backgorund` to your `Button`.
and try `yourBindingvar.executePendingBindings()`. it may Helps You.